# Java - Reference outer class from handlers

Tags: java, android, multithreading, inner-classes

I have a top-level class called Gradebook that sets up event handlers for a Spinner via an anonymous handler, that contains an anonymous thread call

```
this.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3){
            Gradebook.this.pd = ProgressDialog.show((Context)Gradebook.this, (CharSequence)"", (CharSequence)"Loading Grade Book...", true, true);
            Gradebook.this.gradecatitems.clear();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       //I need to reference the top-most level class, GradeBook's members in here
                    }
            }).start();
        });
```

How do I reference the top-level class member from within my Thread? Keep in mind that my thread is an anonymous class already within an anonymous class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd look something like this.-

```
YourClassName.this
```

Comment: So in this case, I could still write something like Gradebook.this.gradecatitems to refer to it from within the thread?

Comment: @Nederealm : yes you have to use Gradebook.this.gradecatitems

Comment: Just tested for two nesting levels, as far as I know, it should work no matter how many levels.

Comment: Didn't noticed you're doing it already from outside the thread. You had the solution in your question :)